# Query on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn data uploading

Tags: scikit-learn

### I have trying to develop machine learning based image classification system using Scikit-Learn. I am trying to do is multi class classification. the biggest problem i am facing with Scikit-Learn is how to load the data. Then I came across one of the examples face_recognition.py. which using fetch_lfw_people to fetch data from internet. I could see this example actually does multi class classification. I was trying to find some documentation on the example but was unable to find. I have some question here, what does fetch_lfw_people do ? what does this function load in the lfw_people. Also what i saw in the data folder there are some text file .is the code reading the text files/? My main intention is to load my set of image data but i am unable to do it with fetch_lfw_people in case i change the path that my image folder by data_home and funneled=False.I get erros, I hope i get some answers here

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. You can't directly give images as an input to your classifier. You have to extract some features from you images. Or you can load your image using opencv and use the numpy array as an input to your classifier. 
I would suggest you to read some basics of image classification , like how you can train your classifier and all.
Coming to your question about fetch_lfw_people function. It might be downloading already pre-processed image data from any text file. If you are training from your images you have to first convert your image data to some numerical features.